# How to say "beginninglessness" properly?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, synonyms

I'm writing about a property of God, describing that He has **no beginning**, and I couldn't find a word for it. The best I came up with is `beginninglessness`, but it sounds alien and doesn't seem to be used in English language.

I'm looking for 1 **noun** with this meaning. I'm stressing on the beginning and trying to avoid a word that would include *has no end* in its meaning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the word for "All Being" (similar to omnipotent for all powerful)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183128/what-is-the-word-for-all-being-similar-to-omnipotent-for-all-powerful)

Comment: http://www.yourdictionary.com/beginninglessness

Comment: This is an interesting question and by no means one that consulting a "general reference" would swiftly answer. In my view, the bigger problem is that there may be no single-word option aside from _beginninglessness_ (which I agree sounds alien and artificial). A more common way to express the philosophical idea of existing prior to the beginning of everything (else), I think, is with a phrase along the lines of "ab initio existence"—that is, existence from the beginning of existence. It's not entirely satisfactory, but you'll probably have to define whatever term you use anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You are exploring the [Cosmological Argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_argument), which hypothesizes a supreme being who is the "[uncaused cause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Cause)". Synonyms included:

- The "***uncaused cause***",
- The "***first cause***"
- The "***unmoved mover***", and
- The "***prime mover***"

See also [Demiurge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demiurge) (which is typically applied to the concept of a supreme being who created the physical universe and set it in motion, but no longer acts or interferes in in, or is now literally gone).

Answer (score 2):

"Eternal" means that He has no beginning and no end.

Comment: Thanks, "eternity" sounds close, but it seems too vague for me. I'm writing about having no beginning only.

Comment: Perhaps "ageless" -- which says that He is ever-new.

Comment: "Omnipresent" means that He is and always has been present everywhere. To invent a new word, he was "antepresent" -- present before-- and "antecreation".

Answer (score 2):

If you look up [*uncreated*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/uncreated), it has two meanings:

> existing, but without having been created,
>   not yet created.

If you are talking about God, it should be quite clear that the first meaning is the intended one.

Answer (score 1):

I think [perpetuity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Perpetuity) may fit the context :

> - the quality of lasting for eternity.
> - the quality of  continuing or lasting for an indefinitely long time.